# How to handle permission and controllers dynamicaly in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1

Assume a site which has bunch of sections having unique URL

```
mysite.com/foo1
mysite.com/foo2
```

this site has users with roles and permissions (note that role & permission are separate model), So i have an admin user and he should be able to set role and permission for user to access those sections! and all of them is dynamic!

I don't think it could be possible by route.php because i can't statically  put them in the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using:

http://heera.it/laravel-5-0-acl-using-middleware

It is a good tutorial to use roles and permissions.

Comment: i have implementation of permissions and roles, but it is static, i mean i should declare permissions in route.php (so this isn't my case )